# Adjusting the numeric label on ggplot while keeping the graph look identical

Tags: r, ggplot2, scale

Say I wish to log10 the x axis of the plot.

```
ggplot(pressure, aes(temperature, pressure)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

One way would be to alter the data or simply, log10 the aes()

```
ggplot(pressure, aes(log10(temperature), pressure)) +
  geom_line()
```

However, above methods would slightly alter the look of the plot.  I would like a plot to look ***identical*** to the first plot, except the label would be {2,2.30103,2.477112,...} So I was wondering if there was an ggplot option to achieve such goal. Something I would imagine as

```
ggplot(pressure, aes(temperature, pressure)) +
  geom_line() +
  imaginary_function(x=log10)
```

Comment: `+ scale_x_continuous(labels = function(x) log(x, 10))`?

Comment: @stefan this worked perfectly.